# Jerky lag on Minecraft OS X

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I've been playing Minecraft for a year now, and have had this weird problem where about 5 minutes after I start playing, the game gets jerky (will lag for a second, then be normal for 2 seconds) and after 5-10 minutes, it stops happening. I don't get why, this is my video settings:

[image: Minecraft Video Settings]

It happens on any texture pack. My MacBook is a late-2009 model, 2.2 GHz, dual core, 4GB RAM. Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: The fact that it stops is interesting. Try turning Advanced OpenGL on, and lowering all the graphics options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your computer is heating up too much. I've noticed that Macs will often wait until they are far too hot before turning the fans up.

It sounds like you start Minecraft, and your computer is cool, then, your computer heats up over a period of five minutes, and starts to go slowly.
Then, your computer turns its fans up, and cools back down to an acceptable level, enabling it to run quickly again.

I recommend using [smcFanControl](http://www.eidac.de). It will display your computer's current temperature, and fan speed, and also allow you to manually force your computer to use its highest fan settings. If you enable the high fan speed before starting Minecraft, then hopefully it won't heat up as much.

You can also try reducing the load the Minecraft is putting on your system.
In my case, I found that using 64 bit Java caused Minecraft to run faster, and at a lower temperature.

I also enable Advanced OpenGL, and reduce the graphics to something slightly less than maximum.